# how do i make better topology for my Alastor model to be rigged?

Tags: rigging, topology, retopology

im making an alastor model, ive been modelling for a few years on blender now but i never really got the hang of face topololy, on the account of me only doing robot characters lmao, i just wanted to ask that when it comes to this character and the messed up topology i have done, im wondering if any of you could advise me on the best way to topologise this face so it is able to be rigged,

the main issue is that the mouth needs to be very expressive, and still have that giant smile as seen in the model, the mouth doesnt close that often but needs to in some expression and shrink a bit, and then the eyes needs a rework along with me trying to figure out how eye lids work

as you can see the mouth is very large but needs to be able to open and close, along with those eyes

if anyone could give some advise i would be most grateful!

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]